# How to use anonymous types with Netflix OData API

Tags: linq, odata

If I create this collection:

```
IEnumerable<_TITLE> _titles = null;
```

How can I set the result set from Netflix in this expression:

```
_titles = from t in Titles where t.Id == "ApUFq" select new {t, t.Cast}
```

I am getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<_Title>'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

I understand it's because I am using an anonymous type.  _TITLE is a custom complex object I create that exposes a subset of Netflix properties.

If I add "_TITLE" in front the of the "new" it says that my object does not implement IENUMBERABLE.

If then _TITLE implements IENUMBERABLE, it says _TITLE does not contain a definition for ADD and still getting conversion error.

Basically, I want to set the _TITLE properties with the data returned from Netflix.  I have defined _TITLE to contain the fields I need, plus a collection of PERSON (for Cast).

Comment: please fix your text so it formats your code correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your generic type is _TITLE, then you need to do  `select new _TITLE {Prop = Value}`.

If you intend to use a generic type, then you need to use `var`:

```
var _titles = from t in Titles where t.Id == "ApUFq" select new {t, t.Cast};
```

So perhaps this is what you meant:

```
var _titles = from t in Titles where t.Id == "ApUFq" select new _TITLE {Title = t};
```

Something along those lines. `var` can be used even if you don't intend to use an anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to vcsjones's answer, You don't need to implement IEnumerable on _TITLE. What's going on is that when you write

```
var foo = new TYPENAME { a, b };
```

it means:

1. create a new TYPENAME, which implements IEnumerable
2. call foo.Add(a) then foo.Add(b);

Example:

```
var names = new List<string> { "Joe", "Mary", "Susan" };
```

As vcsjones mentioned, You need to use Parameter names when initializing an object, or perhaps you meant to use parentheses and call a constructor

```
var title = new _TITLE { Title = t.ID, Cast = t.Cast };
// or
var title = new _TITLE (t.ID, t.Cast);
```

Comment: Why would he need to implement `IEnumerable` on _TITLE? I think the way this is suppose to work is the LINQ operating returns IEnumerable<_TITLE>. The problem I think that was arising was he was using {} as a collection initializer when he meant to use it as an object initializer.